# SELECT query with bindParam returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
    public function showSingleVisit(){
        //echo $this->doctorID; the printed 1111
        //$this->doctorID = 1111; 
        $db = connect_db();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM visit WHERE doctorID = :doctorID";
        $result = $db->prepare($query);
        $result->bindParam(':doctorID', $this->doctorID);
        $result->execute();
        return $result;
    }
```

This query doesn't return any row but when putting `$this->doctorID = 1111` I get the rows that is wanted.  I use `bindParam` in `INSERT` query in this class and works correctly. What's the problem?

UPDATE:

```
   class visit{
       //define public varibles
       public function showSingleVisit(){ 
           $db = connect_db();
           $query = "SELECT * FROM visit WHERE visit = 0 AND doctorID = :doctorID AND patientID =    :patientID";
           $result = $db->prepare($query);
           $result->bindParam(':patientID', $this->patientID);
           $result->bindParam(':doctorID', $this->doctorID);
           $result->execute();
           return $result;
       }
   }
```

Here's how I call the function un the other page:

```
    $visit = new visit;
    $visit->doctorID = $auth->user->IDNo;  
    $visit->caseNo = $_SESSION['caseNo'];
    $result = $visit->showSingleVisit();
        if($result){
            while($row = $result->fetch()){
                echo'<p>
                    <label>Date:</label>
                    <span>'.$row->visitDate.'</span>
                </p>';
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "No exists!";
        }
```

Neither it shows any dates, nor it prints "No exists!".

Comment: `$result->bindParam(':doctorID', $this->doctorID);` takes the value out of `$this->doctorID` and places it into the prepared sql statement. So `$this->doctorID` must contain a value **BEFORE** you execute the `bindParam()` statement, or there is no data to pass to the prepared statement.

Comment: Before calling the function `showSingleVisit()` it has taken a value. I'm using exactly this `bindParam` in another function in the class and it works!

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the type of the param :

```
$result->bindParam(':doctorID', $this->doctorID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

look at here :

```
http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php
```

Answer (score 1):

since doctorID is integer, you should add data_type to INT. it look like this

```php
$result->bindParam(':doctorID', $this->doctorID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: No it doesn't solve it. But I've copied the function codes directly and I got rows without using `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

Comment: glad it has been solved. just out of curiosity, can you tell me the function you copied?

Comment: The function `showSingleVisit()` that I wrote in the question, above. But it's not really satisfying because I wanted it to be in the class.

Comment: @CodeLiker what do you mean the class, how do you have it now , can you update your post

Comment: what about `$this->patientID`? i only see you set value for `$visit->caseNo`.